# How to mitigate the negative karmic effect of killing

Tags: personal-practice, modern-world, lay-buddhism, five-precepts

I'm a graduate student studying plant-insect interactions. My research, necessary for my degree, requires me to collect (kill) a few hundred insects. Are there any suttas, or general Buddhist recommendations, for how a lay person can best approach this? Are there ways to make up for the bad karma incurred by this action?

Answer (score 4):

Wanting to become a degree holder is Bhava-tanha or craving to become. That craving is causing you to break the first precept. See how dependant origination is at play here.

You can either look for insects that are already dead or tell your professor that you cannot kill as a Buddhist.

Comment: If one is not fully enlightened Bhava-Tanha is always "in a person". Since this person in question is not a monk and since precepts are not commandments but training rules he is free to do anything if it helps him. Suffeeing cannot be completepy mitigated and kamma  is largely dependent on one's beliefs. If he does not intentionaly kill with anger but for a higher purpose which is believable to him then kamma won't produce much bad fruit (if at all).

Comment: @Val Karma is not a God who is going to hear your plea. Karma is like fire. Whether a grown man who knows better puts his hand in fire or an infant does it, it will burn.

Comment: Your example is not correct with regards to kamma. If we have 2 wrong doers and one is holding a self compassion belief and the other does not and self denegrates himself instead,  the kammic consequences will differ in both instances (and keep in mind that both person experience the same event).

Comment: It is appropriate as in fire is a natural phenomena and so is Karma. Bhava-tanha is not synonymous with compassion(Karuna). Proximate cause of killing is always aversion. In this case the aversion is caused by the greed to become.

Comment: If you are in the position to kill 5 old people or one young people who is there aversion involved? Similarily, if you decide to hurt an animal because they are biting your little child how is there necessarly anger involved? Besides, even if you are angry your are not spending the rest of your life in hell.

Comment: One cannot decide on sheer will that one will abandon greed and hatred once and for all. Even if we set intentions we still might act contradictory. Why? Because we are fallible, we have limited capacities (in that we sometimes forget new resolutions or overly focus on the short term benefits of the bad things) and often we are just victims of cause and conditions (in that we don't know better coping skills to manage the situation)

Comment: @Val start practicing Satipattana meditation. Then you dont have to kill regardless of whatever situation you are put in. You will simply note the aversion instead of acting on it.

Comment: Sankha, good luck in practising "satipatthana meditation" when you feel aversion because someone wants to kill you or one of your relatives. Just watch it go by. Anicca.. everything is impermanent.

Comment: Luck is not required @Val. Only mindfulness. In any case, there are many ways to avoid such situations without having to kill if you are smart enough.

Comment: Behind a computer screen with a full belly everyone can give big talks. If your or your relative's life is threathened  I am curious to see your mindfulness.

Comment: @Val Ad hominem comments won't contribute to this conversation

Comment: @Val Yes that seemed quite close to wishing ill on Sankha's relative, motivated by curiosity or anger. `:-(` To make the criticism or discussion more "constructive", instead, is there some specific change (an addition, or a rephrasing) which you'd like to see in the answer Sankha posted? I guess you were saying that the answer wasn't helpful, e.g. because Bhava-tanha is normal (especially in a lay person), and that the underlying intention/motivation (e.g. "for a higher purpose which is believable to him") affects how much bad fruit there will be.

Comment: Normal isn't always right or good. If one is able to identify the corrupted mindstate even in situations which people call 'normal', it's will only be beneficial. Taking the view that killing is ok is quiet harmful to the mind.

Comment: Chris, I never meant to be harsh but usually most people know intellectually about higher teachings but don't embody them in real life. Knowing something intellectuall is just 1/3 of the bill.

Comment: @Val that is a comment about your assumption regarding my personal practice. It does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Your best (and only) approach to dealing with *karma* is to understand the Buddhist psychology of *karma*. This psychology is based upon the concept of *sankhara*, a Pali term that can be approximately translated as the English term schema (schemata in plural form). Both concepts are complex and sophisticated psychological constructs. Strictly speaking, *sankhara* can be viewed is a process or as a set of predispositions.

I will start with the process definition because it is easier to understand. **As a process, *sankhara* is the process of selecting a response or action (that may be a mental action or a bodily action) in response to a perceived situation.** This process unfolds in a complex manner under the causal influence of a multitude of factors, such as:

1. past beliefs determined by past experience,
2. innate forms of intelligence that sort out the possible causes and consequences of perceived events and actions,
3. an innate and automatic predisposition that causes us to always select the best action given the circumstances,
4. the process of perception that selects certain events to be significant while ignoring others (based upon past experience), and
5. our experience of “reality” based upon a great multitude of lifetimes.

No matter who we are or how old we are, this process necessarily involves a great deal of intelligence, most of which is unconscious. In Buddhist psychology, we do not have “free will,” as defined by Christian theology. Instead, our choices are determined by how we have understood our past experience. The only source of freedom is knowledge. The better we understand our situation, the better choices we make. There is no equivalent to the Christian concept of blame in Buddhist psychology.

**As a set of predispositions, *sankhara* consists of the psychological causes of the *sankhara* process.** Needless to say, describing a *sankhara* as a cause of behaviour is a daunting process that is drastically reduced by referring to some belief or wish that merely helps to identify a very complex set of causes. This abbreviation of the description of the set of causes of an action is the source of very serious misunderstandings of the nature of *sankhara*. For example, it is a serious blunder to refer to “clinging” as a cause of behaviour. It is also a serious blunder to think that killing an insect somehow automatically has some kind of “negative karmic effect.”

Overall, a great deal of wholesome (*kusala*) *sankhara* is acquired by being a “graduate student studying plant-insect interactions,” because a factual and objective understanding of biological processes is very conducive to wholesome behaviour and understanding. But, independently of whether or not you kill any insects, you lack the deep meditative understanding and appreciation of life itself and its many hidden causes. Through no fault of your own, you have no awareness of the deeper dimensions of the mind. This can be acquired only through many years of mindfulness meditation or *vipassana*.

I wish you well in your practice and suggest that you not be concerned by such a superficial understanding of *karma*. You cannot “make up for the bad karma incurred by this action” because it does not exist. I suggest you meditate on the complex causes of action and come to appreciate the extraordinary dimensions of human intelligence.

Comment: very good answer IMO, and should get more attention

Answer (score 2):

### How to mitigate the negative karmic effect of killing

Generally speaking it can't be done.

Don't kill. Tell your teacher you're a Buddhist.

However, if in this particular case you have made up your mind on killing... At least you can cleanse your own mind. Please perform a Bardo Deliverance ceremony for each insect. Exact details don't matter, what matters is your sincerety, so you can make up the exact ceremony yourself. Should be at least 20 minutes long per insect, first stand on your knees and talk to each insect, explaining why you have to kill it and what benefits it will bring to the world, and asking forgiveness from the insect and the future generations of its children, not to be born because of you. Make it clear that you don't think that you are better or higher than the insect. Then, after you kill it, talk to it again and promise a swift rebirth in a pure land of Tushita, where it can listen to the teachings of Maitreya. Describe what it will look like to live in Tushita heaven and tell the insect how awesome it will be to learn directly from the great Bodhisattva. Make a vow to the world, that through the power of your compassion these promises will actually come true and they will. Say thank you, to each insect individually, for being your teacher at the moment and giving you this lesson on interconnectedness. Have a clear understanding that at that moment the insect is in fact a representative of the Dharmakaya, teaching you.

If other people happen to see you, don't hide. Explain that you are a Buddhist and relay to them the outlines of the ceremony in broad terms. This should seed enough good seeds to offset the negative effects, in this particular case.

This is an overall scheme. Like I said, what matters is your sincerety. Feel free to improvise and elaborate.

Comment: I like this answer so much! You are skillful :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen worst. I have seen people eating animals alive. I have also seen people killing people. Your crime is not too big. You should focus on keeping your heart clean. Keep your conscience clean. If you feel you have done wrong i.e. you have been cruel to insects then ask for forgiveness by practicing non violence for the rest of your life.And promise not to repeat such mistakes. If you feel you have done nothing wrong then ask yourself why it was necessary? How it solved the problems of humanity ?  Keep your conscience clean. If you don't have conscience then you need to develop it by practicing good will and compassion.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the answer you wanted: but I think it's normal for monks to not kill insects. For example, there are monastic rules against their digging in earth which might contain insects.

These specific (monastic) rules don't apply to lay-people. Perhaps it might be seen as an unfortunate reality that lay-people will kill, to some extent: especially as a side-effect of agriculture.

One way to avoid doing that might be to become a monk yourself.

A way to mitigate bad kamma might be to accumulate merit or good kamma (e.g. via generosity, perhaps towards the sangha or, I don't know, perhaps towards insects).

People have also been mentioning the [Lonaphala Sutta (AN 3.99: The Salt Crystal)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html) recently.

Comment: Lay people are not supposed to break the first precept. This question is about deliberately killing insects. Not accidentally killing them.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that your statement is Theravada orthodoxy. But I'm not sure that you and I can agree on the details of this topic. I would agree it's difficult to classify the scientific research as "accidental" killing. However, IMO it's also difficult to classify digging the earth as "accidental" (not "deliberate") killing. I'm also of a view that buying meat is analogous to asking someone to kill on one's behalf. But you've commented previously that a vegetarian diet is no more moral (or perhaps not much more moral) because agriculture still involves the killing of insects.

Comment: [5 conditions](http://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/PDF_BuddhismCourse/11_%20Five%20Precepts.pdf) must be met to break the first precept. When you are digging the earth, there's no knowledge that you are digging on an animal, there's no intention to kill an animal. But in case of killing insects for scientific research, there's clear knowledge that it's a being and there is clear intention to kill. Thus breaking the precept.

Comment: `5 conditions` That's Abhidhamma. `When you are digging the earth, there's no knowledge that you are digging on an animal, there's no intention to kill an animal.` When you are carpet-bombing a city, is there no knowledge that you are bombing on a person, no intent to kill a person?

Comment: Carpet bombing a city is always intended directly to kill people. Digging the earth is (usually) not intended to kill insects, but rather for other purposes like planting crops.

Comment: @YesheTenley I think Sankha wasn't talking about *intention*, though, but about *knowledge*: i.e. do you "know" that you're digging on an animal (because if you don't "know" then it's "accidental").

Comment: @ChrisW can you link to the reference prohibiting digging in the earth for ordained sangha?

Comment: @YesheTenley Pages 269 through 271 of this explanation of [The Patimokkha Rules](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf): `Should any bhikkhu dig soil or have it dug, it is to be confessed`. They may ask a lay person to do it but only indirectly. Digging clean sand is OK. The explanation is for the sake of the *soil*, which is "a form of one-facultied life". That ends with, "Another consideration, carrying more weight at present, is that the act of digging soil risks killing or injuring whatever animals might be living there".

Comment: @YesheTenley I read [an account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Years_in_Tibet) in which labourers in Tibet were digging for some construction work, and their work progressed really slowly because they wanted to gently discover and save (put aside) any worms and insects in the soil. I don't know what current agricultural practices are, but I've little reason to doubt that insects and so on die, as some kind of side-effect -- and IMO this is knowable, predictable.

Comment: @ChrisW intention to kill is one of the 5 conditions. Also when you are carpet bombing there's knowledge that the people you want to kill are in that area. In most cases, they observe the enemy activity to pick the area they want to bomb. That's never the case with digging for agriculture.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Isn't an "intention" mixed, imprecise? "My intention was to protect myself" ... or "to protect other people" ... or "to feed myself when I was hungry". Or, in a science experiment, the intention maybe to isn't to kill, is instead to improve agriculture. In [old-style "carpet-bombing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Dresden_in_World_War_II#Military_and_industrial_profile) (instead of new-style "precision bombing"), the *intentions* included to make the "enemy" want to stop the war; and to reduce their industrial capacity (destroy factories), and disrupt transport.

Comment: I don't want to argue that "farming" and "carpet-bombing" are morally the same: I chose that as an example only because I couldn't think of any other example where you kill (or where the result includes the killing of) lots of people (or creatures, beings) without seeing those people in advance, by destroying the whole area where they live. Someone who ploughs a field doesn't see the insects, but surely they know that insects are there? So apparently this argument depends on your definition of what you can consider "accidental".

Comment: An article [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/chah/heartfood.html) may coincide with your view e.g. `If someone were to ask me to intentionally kill an ant or a termite, to squash one with my hand, for instance, I couldn't do it ... However, it may be that I may cause one to die, such as when something crawls up my leg and I brush it off. Maybe it dies, but when I look into my mind there is no feeling of guilt. There is no wavering or doubt. Why? Because there was no intention.` Even so IMO monks are held to some higher moral standard (e.g. they mustn't dig whereas laypeople do).

Comment: @ChrisW intention is never mixed. One thought can contain only one intention. You feel like it is mixed because thoughts pass by in quick succession. Intention to kill is always cause by aversion and it's always bad Karma. Wanting to pass the exam and deciding to kill do not occur in the same thought. Wanting to save someone is one moment and deciding to kill is another. This becomes clearer if you practice Satipatthana meditation.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Is "aversion" a feeling? It seems to me you're mixing different things: "intention" (i.e. goal or result), "feeling" (e.g. aversion or guilt), "decision" (what action is necessary to achieve the goal), "wanting" (to pass the exam), "knowing" (whether an action will cause insects' deaths), "thought-moments", and so on. I'm not saying you're confused, just that the distinction you make (I think you're saying "that ploughing a field and/or buying meat is done without intention to kill and without knowledge of animals being killed") isn't a doctrine that I wholly agree with.

Comment: @ChrisW Aversion is Dosa(Pali) or disliking. It is a concomitant(Cetasika). Intention to kill is always associated with Dosa.

Comment: Practice mindfulness the next time when you buy meat or dig earth . See if an intention to kill arises.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the four parts of the karmic path get completed. The four parts are basis, intention, action and completion. In this case, the best way would be to stop at the last step and develop intense regret for the action. However if this is a regular action, the regret will not be genuine.

The other is to put the four opposite forces into action.

https://learning.tergar.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/The-Four-Powers-copy.pdf

This requires you to commit to not doing the karma again, at least for a specific duration of time.

The last way is to do the 35 Buddhas confession practice:
https://www.lamayeshe.com/article/chapter/appendix-3-confession-downfalls-thirty-five-buddhas

Answer (score 0):

You are knowingly causing the suffering of sentient beings who want to be happy just as you do. Your actions are non-virtuous and you should stop. Thinking that you can continue doing so and somehow ameliorate your continued bad actions will only cause you to incur heavier debt than already incurred. This is necessarily so because if you convince yourself that you can ameliorate it somehow, then using this as an excuse you will continue to cause harm to yourself and others.

All sentient beings wish to be happy and to avoid suffering - even insects - just as you do. Does that mean that all beings *know how* to achieve happiness? Clearly not! To take an extreme example, human beings who wantonly spread terror by killing and torturing in the name of religious zealotry, obviously do not know how to achieve happiness. They are extremely - to the nth degree - unskillful in the method they are using to try and achieve happiness. Nonetheless, these people wish to be happy and to avoid suffering just as you do. It is exactly the same for all sentient beings.

When you are in a hole... stop digging. Only after you have done this should you make a plan to get out of the hole. Short of this, I think Andrei's answer is excellent. If you practice what Andrei suggests with sincerity and with a mind aspiring for compassion I have no doubt you will stop your non-virtuous actions which will be very good for your - and the insects! - aims to be happy and avoid suffering.

Comment: Some insects wish to spread malaria to kill people. For example, today, for the 1st time ever, government inspectors knocked on my door to inspect my property for places mosquitoes can breed to spread dengue fever. Are you saying that these insects "want to be happy just as you do" by spreading dengue fever & malaria? Are yoy saying mosquitoes are like ISIS terrorists who gain happiness from beheading people? These mosquitoes are programmed by nature. They do not aspire for "happiness". They merely perform limited functions of spreading disease & reproducing.

Comment: I’d actually like to respond and try to learn something from conversation with you, but this looks like argument and the moderators have asked me not to contribute. Nevertheless, I will try and update my answer to address your objections.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77022/discussion-on-answer-by-yeshe-tenley-how-to-mitigate-the-negative-karmic-effect).

Answer (score 0):

Consider letting your material goal go. The Buddha let go of great material success and accepted the Dhamma.

You could even consider putting all your focus on the Dhamma.

We have to learn how to not desire things that will lead to our collective and individual suffering not as only human beings but as just beings. We see these Buddhist "can't kill a fly"  precepts as inconsequential in our hearts. When we kill insects the effects can be so subtle, at a very deep level that we cause our hearts & minds to get more and more tangled.

I'm considering letting go of a small fortune. I haven't done it yet and I can clearly see that I am destroying myself trying to invest all this money for my wife and I. Only rarely can I see at enough of a subtle level to even start to untangle my mind.  Focusing on just the practice is better than spreading the focus and effort around to other projects.

Answer (score -2):

Killing insects is not a offence for monks that leads to expulsion from the monastic community therefore the kamma of killing insects is not something serious. It is kammically "trifling".

For example, insects can spread deadly disease & destroy crops, which shows they are lifeforms that do not have a moral conscience. For this same reason of not having a moral conscience, insects do not suffer when they are killed because their minds cannot generate egoistic attachment. If an insect, such as a mosquito or gadfly, was a rational creature with a mind capable of suffering, a mosquito would not continually return to bite & even kill a human after many loving & gentle attempts of a human to scare the insect away.

The reason a Buddhist, such as monk, refrains from killing insects is to develop a higher than ordinary level of non-violence, gentleness, safety towards all beings, fearlessness, loving-kindness & non-attachment. In other words, there is no serious bad karma for killing an insect, such as killing a mosquito that might bite a small baby. Often, it is a duty rather than bad karma to clean away insects that are threatening to health, life & property.

There is far more serious bad kamma than killing insects, such as watching pornography or having uncommitted sex. You should be aware many internet Buddhists over-esteem non-killing as a "virtue-signalling" to ameliorate themselves from their unwholesome & enslaving sexual deeds.

In respect to your question, the Buddha taught "*kamma is intention*". If your study is for a wholesome intention then that is enough to ameliorate the trifling bad kamma of killing some insects. The results of kamma is something we known within our hearts & minds. I recommend to read the [Lonaphala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html) for guidance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77128/discussion-on-answer-by-dhammadhatu-how-to-mitigate-the-negative-karmic-effect-o).